# How to get content from a tooltip of a marker?

Tags: javascript, typescript, marker

I was added to a project that uses TS to generate de JS of a webpage. The page use markers to signal positions of some cars, and those markers have a popup that shows the name of the person driving. I was asked to add a searcher to filter between those names and leave visible only the markers that match. I've solved it in JS, but since i need to pass this to the TS. Everything was fine until i got to this line:

```
if (a.marker._tooltip._content.toLowerCase().indexOf(sea.toLowerCase()) !== -1)
```

What basically does is take the name in the popup and compare it with what i was searching, and this works on JS, but in TS it gives me an error since _tooltip does not exist on Marker. How could i translate that line to make it work on TS?

Comment: If you want a quick work around you can just do `if ((a.marker as any)._tooltip....)`

Comment: If you want proper fix then tell us more about `marker`'s type. Your description is inadequate.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, has been rough days, the quick answer was enough, problem is that i don't know any of TS, so i couldn't give something very detailed, but still thanks since you solved the problem!